# What is the neatest formula for the coefficients of the composition $f\circ g$ where $f,g$ are formal polynomials or generating functions?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, generating-functions, function-and-relation-composition, formal-power-series

There are well-known formulas for the coefficients resulting from multiplying two formal polynomials or generating functions (we define formal polynomial to be a generating function such that all coefficients of sufficiently high index are zero). Adding is even easier, as it is component-wise.

**Question:** What is the neatest formula for the coefficients of the composition $f\circ g$ where $f,g$ are formal polynomials or generating functions?

I tried approaching it by writing $(f\circ g)(x) = f(g(x))$ and substituting the expression for $g$ into the expression for $f$. Even with summation notation, the expansion just devolved into an mess involving the multinomial theorem that seems difficult to simplify. I am hopeful that combinatorial identities or other techniques such as exchanging the order of the summations will yield a somewhat satisfactory formula. I'll settle for pretty much any non-trivial simplification.

Comment: I don't know of any "nice" formula for the coefficients of the composite of two generating functions. In the case of exponential generating functions, we can relate composition to an operation on [species](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_species) (see the "composition" section of the linked wikipedia article), but in general I don't know of any results. A quick google brings up a paper of Kruchinin [_Composition of Ordinary Generating Functions_](https://arxiv.org/abs/1009.2565v1), but I haven't read it so I'm not sure how neat a result it is.

Comment: It's called Faa di Bruno's formula and yes, it is terrible (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula). It's better not to think about these things directly but conceptually in terms of operations on combinatorial species as HallaSurvivor says.

Comment: What I am doing is to express composition of functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ (having a power series) as matrix-multiplication $F \cdot G$ after each function has a "Carleman"-matrix $F$ resp $G$ assigned. The evolution of coefficients in the matrix-operation is now schematic, but is of course nothing else than the explicite coefficients by the Faa di Bruno - formula. But working with it seems to be more transparent to me ... but it is too much to explain this (and its limits and so on ... ) in a comment.

Comment: Perhaps an interesting introductory discussion might be in https://go.helms-net.de/math/tetdocs/ContinuousfunctionalIteration.pdf while the main focus is not function-composition but iteration. But well, perhaps useful anyway...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for OGF, let $[x^i] f(x) = f_i$ and $[x^j] g(x) = g_j$. Then you can rewrite the composition as
$$
[x^k]f(g(x)) = \sum\limits_i f_i [x^k] g^i(x) = \boxed{\sum\limits_i f_i \sum\limits_{j_1 + \dots + j_i = k} g_{j_1} \dots g_{j_i}}
$$

For EGF, let $\left[\frac{x^i}{i!}\right] f(x) = f_i$ and $\left[\frac{x^j}{j!}\right] g(x) = g_j$, then
$$
\left[\frac{x^k}{k!}\right] f(g(x)) = \sum\limits_i \frac{f_i}{i!} \left[\frac{x^k}{k!}\right] g^i(x) = \boxed{\sum\limits_i \frac{f_i}{i!} \sum\limits_{j_1+\dots+j_i=k} \binom{k}{j_1,\dots,j_i} g_{j_1} \dots g_{j_i}}
$$
I think it doesn't really get prettier than that, and it's indeed better to interpret combinatorially. Informally, if $f(x)$ is the genfunc of species $A$, and $g(x)$ is the genfunc of species $B$, then $f(g(x))$ is the genfunc of species obtained by taking instances of species $A$ and replacing their "atoms" by instances of species $B$.

For example, if $A$ is species of "sets" and $B$ is species of "cycles", then $f(g(x))$ is the genfunc for the species of "sets of cycles", aka "permutations". The meaning of the composition formula for EGFs is then interpreted as "take an instance of $A$ on $i$ atoms, and replace its atoms with instances of $B$ with total of $k$ atoms across them". Then the multinomial coefficient accounts for the number of ways to distribute $k$ new atoms between $i$ instances of species $B$.